# How to fix Expo Android app which can't make more than 2 http request in a row

Tags: android, firebase, axios, firebase-storage, expo

I'm having an ugly issue that only affect my expo app on Android.

Im trying to upload a base64 image taken with expo `ImagePicker` to *Firebase Storage* passing the image value with a http-request made with `axios`  to a *Firebase Cloud Function* which returns the url of the saved image. This url goes in *Firestore*, but this is out of reach of my question I think.

My current implementation works flawless in IOS (I can get as many urls as I want, they upload pretty quick actually) but, in Android I only can upload 2 images in a row; **when I try for the third time, my app get frozen when reach `axios`/`fetch`* statement and gives no clue of whats happened.** Console is just as it was before trying the third time and the apps or simulators freeze.

Here you can see this behaviour in a 2 min video:

https://youtu.be/w66iXnKDmdo

When I begun working in this bug I was using  fetch instead of axios. At that time the issue was that I was able to upload only one image. It were necessary to close and open the app again to upload one more. Now with axios Im able to upload 2 insted of one, but the problem persist.

This is how I implemented the code:

```
const imageBase64 = 'QWEpqw0293k01...'
```

This is how I upload the image to Firebase Cloud Storage:

```
export const savePhoto = (imageBase64) => {
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  const docRef = db.collection('Comidas').doc();
  return () => {
    uploadImageToFirestore(imageBase64)
    .then(imageUrl => {
      console.log('image-url: ', imageUrl);
      docRef.set({ imagen: { uri: imageUrl }, });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log('error: ', err));
  };
};
```

I made a function helper that allow me to make the http request reusable:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const uploadImageToFirestore = (imageBase64) => {
//<--- here is where it get frozen the third time
//<--- console.log() calls three times but not axios
  return axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://us-central1-menuapp-9feb4.cloudfunctions.net/almacenamientoImagen',
    data: {
      image: base64
    },
  })
  .then(res => res.data.imageUrl)
  .catch(err => console.log('error while uploading base64: ', err));
};
```

This invoques the following Firebase Cloud Function:

```
exports = module.exports = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {
    const body = req.body;
    console.log('image: ', body.image);
    fs.writeFileSync("/tmp/uploaded-image.jpg", body.image, "base64", err => {
  console.log(err);
  return res.status(500).json({ error: err });
});
const bucket = gcs.bucket("myapp.appspot.com");
const uuid = UUID();

bucket.upload(
  "/tmp/uploaded-image.jpg",
  {
    uploadType: "media",
    destination: "/comidas/" + uuid + ".jpg",
    metadata: {
      metadata: {
        contentType: "image/jpeg",
        firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: uuid
      }
    }
  },
  (err, file) => {
    if (!err) {
      console.log('url: ', {
        imageUrl:
          "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/" +
          bucket.name +
          "/o/" +
          encodeURIComponent(file.name) +
          "?alt=media&token=" +
          uuid
      });

      res.status(201).json({
        imageUrl:
          "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/" +
          bucket.name +
          "/o/" +
          encodeURIComponent(file.name) +
          "?alt=media&token=" +
          uuid
      });
    } else {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({ error: err });
    }
  }
  );
 });
});
```

I know that axios it’s not being called because there is no log neither register of the Firebase Cloud Function execution.

I expect this code to upload as many images as user consider he/she needs, not just 2 per app session as it does at this moment

How can I solve this?

Comment: What if you wait for one of the images to complete before trying another one. If that works, the library, client, or server may have a limit on the number of connections it allows open between a single client and server pair.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @FrankvanPuffelen. That’s what im doing. What I mean by “in a row” is a complete cycle of the code mentionated above. It takes one image, it get the url and it saves the firestore. This process begin and completes two times. When you try the third time it freeeeze with no feedback at all. I’ll post a short video to better demonstrate the behaviour.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Post updated with the video: https://youtu.be/w66iXnKDmdo

Comment: Hmm.... in that case I have no idea. Hopefully somebody else sees a problem.